# Number.isNaN('asd') === false in Node.js! What gives?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nan

Try it: In Node.js, or Firefox, open a REPL, and type:

```
Number.isNaN('asdf');
```

How can this not be `NaN`? What is `NaN` if not this?

Comment: As an aside, I highly recommend this great JSConf talk - " Everything you never wanted to know about JavaScript numbers -- JSConf EU 2013"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MqHDDtVYJRI
It explains the low-level (Bit-level) details of how "Number" is implemented in JS but in a way that anyone can understand it.

Comment: `Number.isNaN(Number('asdf'))`

Answer (score 3):

You have a misconception here. The fact that `NaN` means *Not a Number* does not mean that anything that is not a number is a `NaN`.

`NaN` is a special value on floating point arithmethic that represents an undefined result of an operation. For example, `0 / 0` generally yields `NaN` as a result.

More information [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN).

Comment: What does what I'm trying to do, `Number.isNaN(parseInt('asd'))`?

Comment: It checks if the value you pass is a `NaN`, that is, *a floating point number* that represents something that is not a number. Is a bit odd if you think about it, but turns out that only numbers can be `NaN`s.

Comment: I want to know if a string can be used as a finite integer. What's a good way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

There is no notion of `Number.isNaN()` in the [language specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.1). The only specified function is the global [`isNaN`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.4) (15.1.2.4), which will correctly return `true` on anything that isn't a number or cannot get correctly transformed into a number.

`Number.isNaN` (which returns true on `NaN`) is <strike>probably an implementation detail</strike>  part of the next standard draft (see [remyabel' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20173683/1139697)) which could be used internally by `isNaN`.

Answer (score 2):

Just a note, it seems that `Number.IsNaN` [has limited support](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/es6/#Number.isNaN).

This output:

```
console.log(Number.isNaN("blabla"));
```

Gives `false`, and `false !== NaN`:

```
console.log(false !== NaN)
console.log(false !== Number.NaN);
```

Here's a [reference](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-number.isnan):

> When the Number.isNaN is called with one argument number, the
>   following steps are taken:
>
> ```
> If Type(number) is not Number, return false.
> If number is NaN, return true.
> Otherwise, return false.
> ```
>
> This function differs from the global isNaN function (18.2.3) is that
>   it does not convert its argument to a Number before determining
>   whether it is NaN.

<sup>I am l33t for I have 1337 reputation.</sup>

Comment: +1: Thanks for the 6th-edition draft, never had a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function checkNaN(value)
{
    return value !== value;
}
```

It works because (I believe) NaN is the only thing in JS that does not strictly equal itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is part of the EcmaScript 6 Standard.

`Number.isNaN` returns whether a value is NaN without coercing the parameter.

```
Number.isNaN("xmfds"); // false
Number.isNaN("ose"); // false
```

`isNaN` returns whether the value is NaN **after** coercing the parameter to `Number` type.

```
isNaN("ose") -> isNaN( Number("ose") ) -> isNaN(NaN); // true
```